# Show included dates in a matrix/table

Tags: user-expectation, design-patterns, tables, dates

I’m stuck on that problem since last friday.

I work for a white-label company. My task here is to display multiple date ranges concerning cancellation fees based on the number of days before the booking start day.

[image: date matrix]

Now the problem is that we don’t understand which day is included. In our system, the first day of the range is included, the second is excluded ; in math, I believe it’s shown like this [a;b[
I guess the typical user won’t understand it at all.

[image]

Does anyone have a clue on that problem?
Did you already encounter it?

Comment: If you know the booked day and price, it would be more helpful to show the booked price, the cancel rate for that moment and the costs of cancellation. Now it is more like help or FAQ information that it should refer to.

Comment: I think we have technical constraints with the back-end, I’ll talk to my PO since this is indeed a cleaner and more understandable solution. Thanks!

Comment: A minor note, but you would represent this mathematically as e.g. `[7, 11)`; see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396290) and [the wiki page linked there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_%28mathematics%29#Including_or_excluding_endpoints).

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can simplify the range by writing like this-

1. Within 2 days
2. In between 2-5 days
3. In between 5-7 days
4. In between 7-12 days
5. after 12 days

This will lessen the cognitive load for the users as it is easier to understand.

Comment: Simple solution and within my constraints. I’ll propose that solution, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest changing the order to fit the user's perception of time:
[image: before and after shhigg review]

I find this helps in getting things into context
as a user, I will find it easier to look at this table and compare it to my schedule. also, if possible - I would add a column that demonstrates a date range for my flight (or an example) and some sort of a disclaimer - do we count every 24 hours from the time of departure or the beginning of each business day? on what timezone... etc

Comment: Minor point you used Cancellation in some spots and Cancelation in other spots.  Should be Cancellation possibly across the board.

Comment: spot on comrade 

Answer (score 0):

If we got to the cancelation dialog, you should probably have all the info about  the appointment, so maybe it'd be much more helpful to show actual dates and times instead of count of days. For example "`Cancel before 29.08.2023 00:00 for a 40% cancelation fee`", and show the actual fee on the cancelation button, as suggested in the comments. This would make it very clear and remove the need for the original problem.

Depending on your users, using mathematical notation for this might introduce a lot of confusion - I've had instances when testers complained about "a glitch in the label" for using `[5, 6)`, turns out it's special knowledge.

Another thing, I'm pretty sure this is a really good case for visualizing the complex data, e.g. like in a sketch below (can be better, it's just a quick suggestion). Don't forget to test it out, though, it might make it more complex if done improperly.

[image: Cancelation fees visualised as vertical bar diagram]

Showing actual dates instead of count of days would probably be a good idea too.